# Drupal Backend Controller is showing HTML Tag

Tags: php, drupal

currently I need to work on drupal backend url for ipay88 payment gateway. I have to send out 'RECEIVEOK' to the server from my backend url. Question is when I do this

```
public function myPage() {
   $element = array(
     '#markup' => 'RECEIVEOK',
   );
   return $element;
}
```

It creates a page on the backend url with my website header and footer. So the server receive the html tags instead of a 'RECEIVEOK' data

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en" dir="ltr" prefix="content:...
```

I am not a developer, I was following guidance from [Here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/introductory-drupal-8-routes-and-controllers-example)
Does anyone know how to solve this please?

Comment: You are using Render Array. That's may be the reason you are getting HTML Tags.Change `#markup` with any other variable name.

Comment: Hi I solved the problem already. What I did was to use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response; which output plain text without any html tags.